# Using .fadein() and .fadeout() with the.text()

Tags: jquery, html

How can i put a .fadein() and .fadeout() on this Jquery code.

This is my paragraph

```
<p id="resultaat"></p>
```

and this is were i change the p with another text

```
$("#resultaat").text("De prijs van "+aantal+" woorden "+"met "+vg+" Als vakgebied is "+totaal+" euro's");
```

I have tryed putting it this way

```
$("#resultaat").text("De prijs van "+aantal+" woorden "+"met "+vg+" Als vakgebied is "+totaal+" euro's").fadeIn();
```

But it didnt work, i am new using Jquery so i dont have that much knowledge in it. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: What is `fatein/fateout`???

Comment: i think its fadeIn and fadeOut?

Comment: @Pekka I think it too but that means OP didn't really put many effort in resolving his issue

Comment: I even doubted myself i erased my first comment lol. @A.Wolff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the element first before using `fadeIn()`

```
$("#resultaat").text("De prijs van "+aantal+" woorden "+"met "+vg+" Als vakgebied is "+totaal+" euro's").hide().fadeIn();
```

Note: You have a typo in `fadeIn()`. It is not `fateIn()`

Comment: yeah my bad was typing it fast!! i ment the fadeIn()